# Xcode messing up with certificate identities and multiple team ids

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When building my App (for Archive) I get:

> You have a valid iOS Distribution certificate in the Member Center,
>   but it is not installed locally. If your signing identity is installed
>   on another Mac, you can export a developer profile on that Mac and
>   import it on this Mac. You can also revoke your current certificate
>   and request a new one.

The Apple documentation suggests that its because I just moved computer. [See link here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html)

However I haven't just moved computer. I am simply trying to upload my build to iTunes connect.

My email is associated to two developer profiles that are both installed on my Mac and hence I believe that Xcode its confusing itself by believing that I have already a profile installed.

For this reason I created a new distribution profile from the member centre, one for **App Store distribution** and one for **ad hoc distribution**. I then dowloaded it and clicked on it. Despite having done so it does not work.

When I click on **Fix issue** I get the message quoted above.

I tried to refresh the details in the Accounts sections of Xcode preferences, but was not of much help.

I believe Xcode is messing up with the team ids.

Is there a way to solve this without revoking and requesting a new certificate?

And if not what is the best way to fix this?

Comment: revoke your certificates and regenerate them

Answer (score 0):

I would try downloading and installing the certificate from the portal.  Then open the KeyChain app and see whether it appears under "My Certificates" section.  If so, that should fix your problem, though check to make sure you don't have duplicates.  If it does not appear, then it means you don't have the private key, and it will not be useable unless you can import the private key.  You probably need to revoke and create a new certificate.